# How can I obfuscate a Symfony PHP Web App?

Tags: php, web-applications, symfony1, obfuscation

I am looking to distribute a symfony web app, but don't want to reveal its source code.

I know it is tough to obfuscate PHP, but I was wondering if there are any closed or open source solutions to obfuscate and/or encode the backend code so that someone receiving the app can run it but wouldn't be able to view the source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[phc](http://www.phpcompiler.org/) (a PHP compiler) has an `--obfuscate` flag

Comment: That seems like the best option, I'll be sure to try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[IonCube](http://www.ioncube.com/) is a PHP encoder. It means that all your customers will need to install the ionCuber libraries on their server, which they may not want to do.

Comment: Ah, quite true. I had a look at their website and balked at their prices... I think I'll try something open source. In the closed source arena there is also Zend Guard as well but their prices are even higher than IonCube (as far as I remember).

Comment: Also you have to remove all annotations or rewrite some symfony files: https://blog.ioncube.com/2019/09/10/using-symfony-with-ioncube-encoder/

Answer (score 0):

I think Ioncube and Zend Guard don't work with symfony because the autoloading.